# how to insert a value to both tables using join codeigniter 4 sql server

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to insert values to both tables at the same time. I'm using a form in my application where I use the inserted values from the form to inert them into the db. But now I'm inserting values to one table (Users).

```
public function registerUser($formdata){

    helper('global');// a heper for randomString().
    //Asign value to columns
    $db_data['Emailaddress'] = $formdata['emailaddress'];
    $db_data['Password'] = password_hash($formdata['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $db_data['Status'] = 'Free';
    $db_data['Token'] = randomString(32);
    $db_data['FirstLogin'] = 0;
    $db_data['Users.UsersKey'] = $db_data['UsersSettings.UsersKey'];
    //insert to db
    $this->db->table('Users', 'UsersSettings')->join('UsersSettings','Users.UsersKey = UsersSettings.UsersKey', 'inner')->insert($db_data);       
} 
public function updateUserSetting_proccess(){
    $formdata = $this->request->getPostGet();
    return $this->SettingsModel->update_user_settings($formdata);
}
```

The content of the Users table is:

```
    SELECT TOP (1000) [UsersKey]
      ,[UniqueID]
      ,[Token]
      ,[ResetToken]
      ,[Emailaddress]
      ,[Password]
      ,[Status]
      ,[DateTimeAdded]
      ,[DateTimeLastUpdated]
      ,[FirstLogin]
    FROM [dbo].[Users]
```

The UsersKey is inserted automaticly because of the auto increment.
The second table I want to use is UsersSettings with content:

```
 SELECT TOP (1000) [UsersSettingsKey]
      ,[UsersKey]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Logo]
      ,[Organization]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Number]
      ,[Addition]
      ,[Postcode]
      ,[City]
      ,[Country]
      ,[Language]
      ,[Theme]
      ,[CalcPercentage]
      ,[CalcAdminFee]
      ,[ColorPrimary]
      ,[ColorSecondary]
      ,[DateTimeLastUpdated]
  FROM [dbo].[UsersSettings]
```

I want the UsersKey from UsersSettings have the same value in Users UsersKey.
I tried this:

```
join('UsersSettings','Users.UsersKey = UsersSettings.UsersKey', 'inner')
```

but it didn't help. Can someong give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to perform the insert into table `Users` first in order to get the generated `UsersKey`.

Explanation of why inserting into table Users first is required, may be shown with the SQL equivalent:

```
declare @lv_UsersKey int

-- insert into table Users (only essential parts shown)
insert into Users(....) values (...)

-- capture UsersKey for inserted record
select @lv_UsersKey = cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)

-- then insert into UsersSettings (only essential parts shown)
insert into UsersSettings (UsersKey, ....) values (@lv_UsersKey, ...)
```

Transferring the above SQL to codeigniter will look like this:

```
$this->db->table('Users')->insert($db_data);
$inserted_users_key = $this->db->insert_id();

$db_data2['UsersKey'] = $inserted_users_key;
// some more init of $db_data2 here

$this->db->table('UsersSettings')->insert($db_data2);
```